# can't paste what I copied line by line with ideaVim line by line

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin, ideavim

### Before copying

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String fruits1 = "appleCake";
    String fruits2 = "bananaCream";
    String fruits3 = "orangeSoda";

    System.out.println("appleCake = " + );
    System.out.println("bananaCream = " + );
    System.out.println("orangeSoda = " + );

}
```

I want to insert a variable on each line using multi cursor

### After copying

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String fruits1 = "appleCake";
    String fruits2 = "bananaCream";
    String fruits3 = "orangeSoda";

    System.out.println("appleCake = " + fruits1);
    System.out.println("bananaCream = " + fruits2);
    System.out.println("orangeSoda = " + fruits3);

}
```

### Use IntelliJ features

[image]

### Use ideaVim features

[image]

What should I set ideaVim settings to perform the same behavior as the IntelliJ function?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is a behavior of IdeaVim. You can file an issue using the [tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/VIM).

Comment: understood. Reported a problem. Thank you. [VIM-1869](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/VIM-1869)